# Using READ UNCOMMITTED with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that's in development, with multiple `UNION ALL` statements.  This is historical data, and I've been instructed to use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`.  Setting aside the discussion over whether this is the right method, I'd like to know if I need to specify this ISOLATION LEVEL only once at the top of the stored procedure, or if I need to specify it after every UNION ALL, since they're different queries?

Example:

```
Alter procedure dbo.ExampleProcedure as
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @EndDate datetime
insert into myDB.DBO.InboundCalls

select I.Date, I.System, Count(*) as calls
from
(select Date, System, CallID from System1CallData C
Left Join someothertables as S on C.CallID = S.CallID
where (C.date >= @StartDate and C.date < @EndDate)) as I
Group by I.Date, I.System

Union ALL

select I.Date, I.System, Count(*) as calls
from
(select Date, System, CallID from System2CallData C
Left Join someothertables as S on C.CallID = S.CallID
where (C.date >= @StartDate and C.date < @EndDate)) as I
group by I.Date, I.System

Union ALL

select I.Date, I.System, Count(*) as calls
from
(select Date, System, CallID from System3CallData C
Left Join someothertables as S on C.CallID = S.CallID
where (C.date >= @StartDate and C.date < @EndDate)) as I
Group by I.Date, I.System
Order by I.Date asc, I.System asc, calls asc
```

So do I put `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` after `Alter Procedure dbo.ExampleProcedure as`, or before the first `SELECT`, or before each nested `SELECT`?  Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Before the `insert into...`, not before the `select...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to know if I need to specify this ISOLATION LEVEL only once at the top of the stored procedure . . .

Only once at the top of the procedure, unless of course you're switching isolation levels *within* the procedure. The [isolation level reverts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) to the previous level when the SP exits.

> If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or
>   trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset
>   to the level in effect when the object was invoked. For example, if
>   you set REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the batch then calls a stored
>   procedure that sets the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, the isolation
>   level setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ when the stored procedure
>   returns control to the batch.

Using the "read uncommitted" isolation level *probably* isn't risky on historical data. I'd presume the person instructing you to use that isolation level knows the risks and has determined that it's safe.

Historical data usually either doesn't change at all, or it changes at known intervals. (Say, quarterly. Or daily at 1:00 am.) I'd expect relatively few people to have insert privileges on those tables, and almost nobody to have update and delete privileges.

You might also test running three separate insert statements within a single transaction, rather than inserting the union of three select statements. The ORDER BY clause is probably a bad idea in production.

Comment: @GunslingerFyre: You're welcome. I've added some info you might find useful. You don't seem very active on SO, but you should know that you can both upvote *and* accept answers.

Comment: @Mike and you should know that [voting up requires 15 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), which the OP would have if you'd have up-voted their question. :-)

Comment: ...just saying, it goes both ways. If the question were good enough to answer, it was probably also good enough for you to up-vote.

Comment: "probably isn't risky on historical data" but probably doesn't have much benefit either. It shouldn't be getting blocked by concurrent activity and SQL Server already can skip taking row locks at read committed if the page hasn't been updated lately.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', I tried to upvote your answer, but as Aaron stated, I don't have enough rep :)  Actually, now I DO have enough rep, so I upvoted.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the input, I was informed that my queries were interfering with others running on linked servers I use in my queries. Just doing as I'm told.